# cmake Not Detecting Library Files Within Conda Environment

Tags: cmake, anaconda, conda

I am trying to work with the Conda installation instructions for Geant https://geant4-userdoc.web.cern.ch/UsersGuides/InstallationGuide/html/index.html#conda-on-linux-macos

```
# Basic steps to setup environment
conda create -c conda-forge --name <my-environment> geant4
conda activate <my-environment>
```

I then go to compile one of the examples with the following commands which complains about missing library files:

```
~$ cmake ~/.conda/envs/geant4/share/Geant4/examples/basic/B1/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find EXPAT: Found unsuitable version "2.4.7", but required is at
  least "2.5.0" (found /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:592 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindEXPAT.cmake:65 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.cmake:47 (find_package)
  /home/user1/.conda/envs/geant4/lib/cmake/Geant4/Geant4Config.cmake:268 (find_dependency)
  CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user1/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

From running `conda list` and I can see all modules and their respective library.so files have been installed to the environment. But `cmake` struggles to pull in the library files from the Conda environment.

I have tried adding the Conda Environment to the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and configuring a line in the cmake file to explicitly look in `~/.conda/envs/geant4/lib`, but `cmake` still doesn't pick up the library directory and falls back to the main system library directory.

```
CMakeLists.txt < add the following
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "~/.conda/envs/geant4/lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

I'm unsure why `cmake` isn't considering the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or enforcing the library location in the Geant4/B1 example CMake file.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following environment appeared to do the job.

Setting a `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` allowed cmake to compile with the include and lib directory provided by the Conda environment.

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/user1/.conda/envs/geant4/
```